# D3.js line that follows cursor regardless of zoom

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Running D3 v6.

This is a multi part question as in trying to solve the original problem I have a question about D3 and mouseevents. A quick note while using my fiddle, if you press the `ESC` key it will clear the draw line behavior.

1. How to draw a line from one node to another, following the cursor, regardless of zoom level and pan position?
2. Why does the line I draw behave differently when the `.on('mousemove')` is applied to an `svg` versus a `g` element?

**Problem 1.** The problem I am facing is that when panning and zooming, the end point of the line does not follow the cursor properly because the container I'm zooming on had it's `x` and `y` translated. Zoom in and click on a node to see the issue.

[Related fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jrymer/ftv94rzk/28/)

This works just fine in my demo, until zooming and panning are involved. I've managed to take care of the panning issues by using `d3.zoomTransform()` to get the current `[x,y]` and apply that to the end point of the line. I cannot figure out to accommodate the zoom level though. I have tried `transform(scale(zoomLevel.k))` but this doesn't work great. To recreate this issue, click a node without panning/zooming and observe the line follows the cursor. Zoom the graph and then click a node and observe the line does not follow the cursor.

**Problem 2.** I thought that I could solve the above issue by having the cursor react to mouse events on the `g` element I use for zooming and positioning rather than my parent `svg` element. When the `mousemove` event is on the `g` the line follows the cursor regardless of zoom/pan but is very laggy and I don't understand why.

[SVG mouseevent](https://jsfiddle.net/jrymer/ftv94rzk/28/)

[G mouseevent](https://jsfiddle.net/jrymer/ftv94rzk/30/)

Brief code overview, view fiddles for full code

```
let sourceNode;

const svg = d3.select("#chart")
  .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height]);
const g = svg.append('g');
const drawLine = g.append('line').attr('stroke', 'red').attr('stroke-width', 5).attr('visibility', 'hidden')
const nodes = g.append(//do node stuff)
const links = g.append(//do link stuff)

svg.call(d3.zoom().on('zoom', (event) => {
    g.attr('transform', `translate(${event.transform.x}, ${event.transform.y}) scale(${event.transform.k})`)
  }))

node.on('click', (event, d) => {
    sourceNode = d
})

svg.on('mousemove', (event) => {
  if (sourceNode) {
  const currentZoom = d3.zoomTransform(svg.node());
    drawLine
      .attr('visibility', 'visible')
      .attr('x1', sourceNode.x)
      .attr('y1', sourceNode.y)
      // Remove the currentZoom offset and observe the line being jank
      .attr('x2', d3.pointer(event)[0] - currentZoom.x)
      .attr('y2', d3.pointer(event)[1] - currentZoom.y);
  }
})
```

Comment: The filddle for 'Related fiddle' (https://jsfiddle.net/jrymer/ftv94rzk/28/) doesn't seem to have a problem ?

Comment: @RobinMackenzie zoom in then click on a node, see that the line acts weird

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for code! I used it.

As for the answer, change this lines:

> ```
> .attr('x2', d3.pointer(event)[0] / currentZoom.k - currentZoom.x / currentZoom.k)
> .attr('y2', d3.pointer(event)[1] / currentZoom.k - currentZoom.y / currentZoom.k);
> ```

**currentZoom.k** - is the current scale